# CSS Grid auto placement of children if available space

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, css-grid

I'm trying to setup a CSS grid with fixed number of columns and auto placement of children if there is enough available space on a row above.

For this example, I have a square grid of 12 cols & 12 rows (cols,rows) and 3 children of size (6,6), (8,5), (4,4).

The last child of size (4,4) has enough space to be placed on the first row of the grid, but it doesn't without defining the `grid-start-row` property.

I've tried `repeat(auto-fit, ...)` & `repeat(auto-fill, ...)` on the grid parent but then I cannot have a fixed length of columns & rows.

### Actual result

[image]

### Expected result

Box with id=2 should be displayed on first row, nothing else is modified.

### Code

The following code is in React & offers some components to tackle this problem : [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-wiles-7p6q9?file=/src/App.js).

#### Grid (parent, child, resizable)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

type GridBoxProps = {
  gridColumnStart: number;
  gridRowStart: number;
  gridColumnEnd: number;
  gridRowEnd: number;
  children: React.ReactNode;
} & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>;

const GridBox = ({
  gridColumnStart,
  gridRowStart,
  gridColumnEnd,
  gridRowEnd,
  children,
  ...props
}: GridBoxProps) => {
  const { style, className, ...otherProps } = props;

  const styles: React.CSSProperties = {
    ...style,

    // grid child props
    gridColumnStart: gridColumnStart ?? "auto",
    gridRowStart: gridRowStart ?? "auto",
    gridColumnEnd: `span ${gridColumnEnd}`,
    gridRowEnd: `span ${gridRowEnd}`
    // ...
  };

  console.log("on dumb component", gridColumnEnd, gridRowEnd);

  return (
    <div style={styles} className={className} {...otherProps}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

type GridResizableBoxProps = {
  axis: "both" | "horizontal" | "vertical" | "none";
} & GridBoxProps;

const GridResizableBox = ({ axis, ...props }: GridResizableBoxProps) => {
  const {
    style,
    className,
    children,
    // gridColumnStart,
    // gridRowStart,
    gridColumnEnd,
    gridRowEnd,
    ...otherProps
  } = props;

  const [size, setSize] = useState({
    width: gridColumnEnd,
    height: gridRowEnd
  });

  const handleResize = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>,
    axis: "height" | "width",
    delta: number
  ) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (axis === "height") {
      if (size.height >= 12 && delta > 0) {
        // in case something breaks, uncomment the following block to reset item's size to its max
        // setSize({ ...size, height: 12 });
        return;
      }
      if (size.height <= 2 && delta < 0) {
        // in case something breaks, uncomment the following block to reset item's size to its max
        // setSize({ ...size, height: 2 });
        return;
      }
      setSize({
        ...size,
        height: size.height + delta
      });
    } else if (axis === "width") {
      if (size.width >= 12 && delta > 0) {
        // in case something breaks, uncomment the following block to reset item's size to its max
        // setSize({ ...size, width: 12 });
        return;
      }
      if (size.width <= 2 && delta < 0) {
        // in case something breaks, uncomment the following block to reset item's size to its max
        // setSize({ ...size, width: 2 });
        return;
      }
      setSize({
        ...size,
        width: size.width + delta
      });
    }
  };

  const styles = {
    ...style,

    // resizable props
    // resize: axis,
    overflow: "auto"
    // ...

    // resized props
    // width: `span ${size.width}`
    // height: `span ${size.height}`
  };

  console.log("on controller", size);

  return (
    <GridBox
      gridColumnEnd={size.width}
      gridRowEnd={size.height}
      style={styles}
      className={className}
      {...otherProps}
    >
      <button onClick={(event) => handleResize(event, "width", 1)}>w+</button>
      <button onClick={(event) => handleResize(event, "width", -1)}>w-</button>
      <button onClick={(event) => handleResize(event, "height", 1)}>h+</button>
      <button onClick={(event) => handleResize(event, "height", -1)}>h-</button>
      <p>
        {size.width}, {size.height}
      </p>
      {children}
    </GridBox>
  );
};

type GridGridProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
} & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>;

const GridGrid = ({ children, ...props }: GridGridProps) => {
  const { style, className, ...otherProps } = props;

  const styles = {
    ...style,

    // grid parent props
    display: "grid",
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr))", // auto-fit, auto-fill
    gridTemplateRows: "repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr))",
    gridGap: "2rem"
    // ...
  };

  return (
    <div style={styles} className={className} {...otherProps}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export { GridGrid, GridBox, GridResizableBox };
```

#### Main

```js
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const WithGrid = () => {
  const gridBoxResizableLayout = [
    {
      id: 0,
      axis: "both",
      gridColumnEnd: 6,
      gridRowEnd: 6,
      style: { boxShadow: "inset 0 0 0 1px red" }
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      axis: "both",
      gridColumnEnd: 8,
      gridRowEnd: 5,
      style: { boxShadow: "inset 0 0 0 1px red" }
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      axis: "both",
      // gridRowStart: 1,
      // gridColumnStart: 7,
      gridColumnEnd: 4,
      gridRowEnd: 4,
      style: { boxShadow: "inset 0 0 0 1px red" }
    }
  ];

  return (
    <GridGrid
      style={{
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100vw"
        // boxShadow: "inset 0 0 0 3px blue"
      }}
    >
      {gridBoxResizableLayout.map((box) => (
        <GridResizableBox key={box.id} {...box}>
          <p>{box.id}</p>
        </GridResizableBox>
      ))}
    </GridGrid>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <div className="App">
      <WithGrid />
    </div>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `grid-auto-flow` property to `row dense` solved it !

[grid-auto-flow reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow)